# Regex lookahead based on url

Tags: python, regex

How would I do the following in regex?

```
>>> s=u'https://cdn-a.sonyentertainmentnetwork.com/grc/images/ratings/hd/eirin/R-18.png'
>>> s.split('/')[-1].split('.png')[0].replace('_','-').upper()
'R-18'
```

It should be to get the item between the last `/` and `png`. The following (which I currently have) is way too greedy --

```
re.search('/(.+)\.png',s).group()
```

Comment: Do `[^/]*\.png$`

Comment: See https://ideone.com/hBMEP9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No regex needed, actually:

```
url = "https://cdn-a.sonyentertainmentnetwork.com/grc/images/ratings/hd/eirin/R-18.png"
try:
    last = url.split('/')[-1]
    file = last.split('.')[0]
    print(file)
except:
    pass
```

This yields

```
R-18
```

---

If you insist:

```
import re
url = "https://cdn-a.sonyentertainmentnetwork.com/grc/images/ratings/hd/eirin/R-18.png"

rx = re.compile(r'([^/.]+)\.png$')
match = rx.search(url)
if match:
    print(match.group(1))
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/UKddxd/2/).

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you use `urllib` and `os.path` for that?

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
s=u'https://cdn-a.sonyentertainmentnetwork.com/grc/images/ratings/hd/eirin/R-18.png'
a=urlparse(s)
import os
p=a.path                        # /grc/images/ratings/hd/eirin/R-18.png
bn=os.path.basename(p)          # R-18.png
print(os.path.splitext(bn)[0])  # R-18
```

For python2 replace the first import with `from six.moves.urllib.parse import urlparse`

Answer (score 2):

You could define `/` as delimiter and used it in a negated character class:

```
[^\/]*\.png$
```

Python:

```
re.search('[^\/]*\.png$', s).group().replace('_', '-')
```

Or if you want to capture name only:

```
>>> re.search('([^\/]*)\.png$',s).group(1)
'R-18'
```